# Oracle SQL create records based on DATES

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

In desperate need of help from all Oracle SQL guru's. Need to generate output for effective and discontinue dates factoring in 2 other dates namely promo_prep date and promo_start date.

I need to check if promo_prep is greater than eff and less DISC. If it is then become the new disc and the new eff for the next row. Up until the promostart date, so if eff and disc changes happen between promo dates they should remain. Only when promo dates fall between EFF and DISC do they need to be applied and create a new record. Images shown below. Appreaciate any help with this query.

Thank you

***Table view before transformation***

[image]

***Desired Ouput***

[image]

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1
( item        varchar2(20),
  loc         varchar2(20),
  qty         number,
  eff         date,
  disc        date,
  promo_prep  date,
  promostart  date
);
--
Insert into TEST1
   (ITEM, LOC, QTY, EFF, DISC, 
    PROMO_PREP, PROMOSTART)
 Values
   ('item1', 'loc1', 280, TO_DATE('11/29/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('1/10/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
    TO_DATE('1/8/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('1/16/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into TEST1
   (ITEM, LOC, QTY, EFF, DISC, 
    PROMO_PREP, PROMOSTART)
 Values
   ('item1', 'loc1', 300, TO_DATE('1/10/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('1/14/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
    TO_DATE('1/8/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('1/16/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into TEST1
   (ITEM, LOC, QTY, EFF, DISC, 
    PROMO_PREP, PROMOSTART)
 Values
   ('item1', 'loc1', 310, TO_DATE('1/14/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('1/1/2999', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
    TO_DATE('1/8/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('1/16/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
COMMIT;
```

Comment: For some mysterious reasons (maybe because you included DDL) no one pointed out that YOU SHOULD NEVER USE IMAGES IN QUESTIONS.  Which you should never do. Never.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate three possible pairs of effective and discontinue dates for each row and then unpivot the result:

> ```
> with prep as (
>   select
>     item, loc, qty,
>     eff as eff1,
>     least(disc, promo_prep) as disc1,
>     least(disc, promo_prep) as eff2,
>     least(disc, promostart) as disc2,
>     least(disc, promostart) as eff3,
>     disc as disc3
>   from test1
> )
> select *
> from prep
> unpivot (
>   (eff, disc) for type_ in (
>     (eff1, disc1) as 'before_promo',
>     (eff2, disc2) as 'promo',
>     (eff3, disc3) as 'after_promo'
>   )
> )
> /*Include only valid combin*/
> where eff < disc
> ```

| ITEM | LOC | QTY | TYPE_ | EFF | DISC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | loc1 | 280 | before_promo | 2022-11-29 | 2023-01-08 |
| item1 | loc1 | 280 | promo | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-10 |
| item1 | loc1 | 300 | promo | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-14 |
| item1 | loc1 | 310 | promo | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-16 |
| item1 | loc1 | 310 | after_promo | 2023-01-16 | 2999-01-01 |

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09ab9/6)

**UPD**:
If it is possible to have non-overlapping intervals, then you need to check this condition before date calculation. Below is updated script.

> ```
> with prep as (
>   select
>     item, loc, qty,
>     case
>       when promo_prep < disc and promostart > eff
>       then eff
>     end as eff1,
>     case
>       when promo_prep < disc and promostart > eff
>       then least(disc, promo_prep)
>     end as disc1,
>     case
>       when promo_prep < disc and promostart > eff
>       then least(disc, promo_prep)
>     end as eff2,
>     case
>       when promo_prep < disc and promostart > eff
>       then least(disc, promostart)
>     end as disc2,
>     case
>       when promo_prep < disc and promostart > eff
>       then least(disc, promostart)
>     end as eff3,
>     case
>       when promo_prep < disc and promostart > eff
>       then disc
>     end as disc3,
>     case
>       when promo_prep >= disc or promo_prep is null or promostart <= eff or promostart is null
>       then eff
>     end as eff4,
>     case
>       when promo_prep >= disc or promo_prep is null or promostart <= eff or promostart is null
>       then disc
>     end as disc4
>   from test1
> )
> select *
> from prep
> unpivot (
>   (eff, disc) for type_ in (
>     (eff1, disc1) as 'before_promo',
>     (eff2, disc2) as 'promo',
>     (eff3, disc3) as 'after_promo',
>     (eff4, disc4) as 'no_promo'
>   )
> )
> /*Include only valid combinations*/
> where eff < disc
> ```

which for this sample data

| ITEM | LOC | QTY | EFF | DISC | PROMO_PREP | PROMOSTART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item4 | loc4 | 280 | 2022-11-29 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-09 |
| item4 | loc4 | 300 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-14 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-25 |
| item4 | loc4 | 310 | 2023-01-14 | 2023-01-25 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-25 |
| item4 | loc4 | 311 | 2023-01-25 | 2023-10-01 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-25 |
| item4 | loc4 | 312 | 2023-10-01 | 2999-01-01 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-25 |

returns this output

| ITEM | LOC | QTY | TYPE_ | EFF | DISC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item4 | loc4 | 280 | before_promo | 2022-11-29 | 2023-01-08 |
| item4 | loc4 | 280 | promo | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-09 |
| item4 | loc4 | 280 | after_promo | 2023-01-09 | 2023-01-10 |
| item4 | loc4 | 300 | promo | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-14 |
| item4 | loc4 | 310 | promo | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-25 |
| item4 | loc4 | 311 | no_promo | 2023-01-25 | 2023-10-01 |
| item4 | loc4 | 312 | no_promo | 2023-10-01 | 2999-01-01 |

Comment: @B-Rad I've seen you comment, but I've supposed that intervals are intersected in appropriate way (so you check everything you need before you place them in a row). For this case you need to add conditions on intersection to each date calculation. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07fbcd/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty straightforwardly by just appending a row when `promo_prep` is between the `eff` and `disc` dates

```
select
  item,
  loc,
  qty,
  eff,
  case 
    when promo_prep between eff and disc then promo_prep
    else disc
  end as disc
from test1

union all

select
  item,
  loc,
  qty,
  promo_prep as eff,
  disc
from test1
where 
  promo_prep between eff and disc
```

| ITEM | LOC | QTY | EFF | DISC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | loc1 | 280 | 2022-11-29T00:00:00Z | 2023-01-08T00:00:00Z |
| item1 | loc1 | 300 | 2023-01-10T00:00:00Z | 2023-01-14T00:00:00Z |
| item1 | loc1 | 310 | 2023-01-14T00:00:00Z | 2999-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| item1 | loc1 | 280 | 2023-01-08T00:00:00Z | 2023-01-10T00:00:00Z |

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41bf70/10)